# Selenium cannot find element in chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

SetUpTest:

```
public void SetupTest()
{
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    selenium = new DefaultSelenium(
        "localhost",
        4444,
        "*googlechrome C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", 
        "http://localhost");
    selenium.Start();
    verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Test function:

```
[Test]
public void LoginTest()
{
    selenium.Open("http://localhost:8085/");

    // login
    for (int second = 0; ; second++)
    {
        if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
        try
        {
            if (IsElementPresent(By.CssSelector("#username"))) break;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("admin");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("123456");
    driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".btn.btn-primary")).Click();
}

private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
{
    try
    {
        driver.FindElement(by);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I download Chrome Driver at this link: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

The newest version is 2.7.

My chrome version is  31.0.1650.63.

The problem is, driver cannot find element, although it exists in view.

How to make it work?

Comment: You appear to be mixing technologies here. Why are you using Selenium RC & WebDriver together? I'm not surprised this doesn't work. Start again. Read the documentation.

Comment: I use Selenium IDE as chrome add-on and it cannot find the element too if I use "verify element present". However If I click the magnifier icon it shows me that element on the page... Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend Selenium IDE and login manually while recording in Selenium IDE. It will help you identifying the correct names of the elements you want to select.

I use something like that

```
using Selenium;

ISelenium sel = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "");
sel.Start();
sel.Open("www.whateveryourwebsideis.com");

sel.Type("id=user_email", "username");
sel.Type("id=user_password", "password");
sel.Click("name=commit");
```

**Update:**
seems to me as if you don't use your IDriver to navigate.

You have

```
selenium.Open("http://localhost:8085/");
```

but I guess you should use

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:8085/");
```

Try

```
string htmlSource = driver.PageSource;
```

after loading the page to check if you actually have any HTML to search elements in.

I just tried installing ChromeDriver but it doesn't really work and I don't actually need it, so I'm afraid I have to leave it to you to find a solution...good luck.

Comment: It's work!!! Please help me make it work with `driver` :) Why driver cannot identifying right element?

Comment: for some reason the driver never worked for me, so I just used ISelenium class. Not sure what's the difference and why both exist...but since ISelenium works fine for me, I never tried driver...so sorry mate, can't help you with that.

Comment: Either use RC or WebDriver - stop mixing them. I would highly suggest the reason why using the ChromeDriver "never worked" is because you are doing this.

Comment: @skhro87: `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:8085/");` <-- it's save me :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Hope you read what Arran wrote...don't mix up RC and WebDriver.